# Mesos, Marathon, Docker, Wildfly

Tags: docker, wildfly, mesos, marathon

I have 3 node Mesos cluster with Marathon framework. On slaves i have Docker and I want deploy few Wildfly instances on one node.
How can i deploy few instances of Wildfly docker containers on one slave Mesos node by Marathon?

Answer (score 2):

deploying a [docker container using marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html) is usually straight forward.
Do I understand correctly that want to deploy several containers onto a single slave? In that case you should look at [marathon's contraints](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/docs/docs/constraints.md).